# Get all images of a xcode project folder in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray, directory

I have a "memes" folder in my project. I want to load all these images (with different names) in an NSArray. How can I do? Thanks, Davide

Comment: Do you have a 'group' or a 'folder reference'? There is a very large difference between the two.